# Change only color of * in div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I was wondering is there a way to change only color of * in label? I have something like this:

```
<label>Name*</label>
```

and I want to change color of that * to get something like this

```
<label>Name<color='red'>*</color></label>
```

Is that possible with jquery? I know there is wrap in jquery, but can I wrap just one character,in this case * ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: are you doing this for jquery form validation?  if so, there are better ways :)

Comment: Yes, but I need this before validation...this answer bellow works fine :)

Comment: A css workaround... [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tFWp5/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('label').html($('label').html().replace('*','<span style="color:red">*</span>'));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtge6/)

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
$('label').html(function(i, html){
    return html.replace('*', '<color="red">*</color>')
})
```